# Modify an observable stream using pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am struggling a bit learning rxjs operators.

```
ConvInterface {
  id: string;
  message: MessageInterface[];
}

MessageInterface {
  id: number;
  content: string;
  convId: string; 
}
```

I have:

```
conversations$: Observable<ConvInterface[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.conversations$ = this.store.pipe(select(conversationsSelector));
  
  //let's say i have a message
  let message: MessageInterface = {
    id: ...,
    content: ...,
    convId: ...
  }
  // here I want to push the message into the specific conversation
  this.conversations$.pipe(
  // here should be the code
  )
}
```

My goal is to push a new message using pipe to the specific conversation's message array. Every message has a convId so i can find the right conversation.

Comment: could you share more of your code

Comment: What is the type of your source steam ?

Comment: @MehyarSawas here it is

Comment: What do you want your final Observable to emit? What is the exact desired outcome here? Are the conversations stored in some kind of store architecture? Do you have your actions set up?